# Google Analytics - screenName xml tag not used

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm trying to manually send screen hits (as I use a mix of Activities and Fragments) and converting the screen name to a pre-configured one in the xml-file.

Doesn't the tracker use the specified xml screenName when manually 
sending screen hits?

**Expected:**
To find "Expected Name" as screen name in Google Analytics dashboard

**Actually found** The class name "com.example.fragment.MyFragment" in Google Analytics dashboard

Code:

```
GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
Tracker t = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
t.setScreenName(MyFragment.class.getName());
t.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
```

XML file global_tracker:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">false</bool>

    <screenName name="com.example.fragment.MyFragment">Expected Name</screenName>

    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXXXXXX-1</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: Have you found solution? I've similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32650148

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are defining the screen name programmatically in this line:

```
t.setScreenName(MyFragment.class.getName());
```