# screenName in XML configuration not working

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I just added support for Google Analytics to my app, and I can't make `<screenName>` in XML configuration to work:

The configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
    <screenName name="com...ActivityMain">Main</screenName>
    <screenName name="com...ActivitySettings">Settings</screenName>
</resources>
```

I Manifest, I have:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource" android:resource="@xml/analytics" />
```

And in Application I have:

```java
synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker() {
    if (mTracker == null) {
        final GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        //analytics.setDryRun(BuildConfig.DEBUG);
        analytics.enableAutoActivityReports(this);
        // To enable debug logging use: adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
        mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
        mTracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true);
        mTracker.enableExceptionReporting(true);
    }
    return mTracker;
}
```

When I enable `VERBOSE` debug, I see this:

```
Loading global XML config values
```

But then, this:

```
Hit delivery requested: ht=1442573034900, _s=78, _v=ma7.8.95, a=1607163793, aid=cz..., an=XXX, av=0.10.2+801d661, cd=com...ActivitySettings, cid=..., sc=start, sr=768x1184, t=screenview, tid=UA-XXX-2, ul=cs-cz, v=1
```

And as you can see, `cd` contains the whole package name.